# Password input type="password" is displayed like "text" on screen?

Tags: forms, input, text, passwords

I've installed a plugin and I'm happy with it- until it comes to the password field section of the registration form. For some inexplicable reason the password is displayed as text upon entry, forcing the user to first actively press the "hide password" button to hide it. So by default the field input is displayed as "text" on screen and not "password". However, here is the code...

```
function bp_nouveau_signup_form( $section = 'account_details' ) {
    $fields = bp_nouveau_get_signup_fields( $section );
    if ( ! $fields ) {
        return;
    }

    foreach ( $fields as $name => $attributes ) {
        if ( 'signup_password' === $name ) {
            ?>
            <label for="pass1"><?php esc_html_e( 'Choose a Password (required)', 'buddypress' ); ?></label>
            <div class="user-pass1-wrap">
                <div class="wp-pwd">
                    <div class="password-input-wrapper">
                        <input type="password" data-reveal="1" name="signup_password" id="pass1" class="password-entry" size="24" value="" <?php bp_form_field_attributes( 'password', array( 'data-pw' => wp_generate_password( 12 ), 'aria-describedby' => 'pass-strength-result' ) ); ?> />
                        <button type="button" class="button wp-hide-pw">
                            <span class="dashicons dashicons-hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="pass-strength-result" aria-live="polite"><?php esc_html_e( 'Strength indicator', 'buddypress' ); ?></div>
                </div>
                <div class="pw-weak">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="pw_weak" class="pw-checkbox" />
                        <?php esc_html_e( 'Confirm use of weak password', 'buddypress' ); ?>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

... as you can see it is already set to <input type="**password**" .... So it doesn't make sense to an amateur like me.

The... <?php bp_form_field_attributes( 'password', `array( 'data-pw' => wp_generate_password( 12 ), 'aria-describedby' => 'pass-strength-result'` )... simply autogenerates and fills the field with an autogenerated password. When using this part it would of course make sense to display the autogenerated password as text first, but that wont be the case for me.

I'm trying to achieve a default setup, that hides the key inputs on screen by default upon password-entry, instead of the other way around like it is now.

All the help is appreciated!